# Find all tables in a snapshot replication that have primary keys

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, query, primary-key

I've been tasked with moving all tables in a single snapshot replication that have primary keys to the transaction replication.

I've tried to break it down into two steps, finding all tables in a snapshot replication, and then checking to see if those tables have a primary key.

I've tried to piece together a few different code samples, but I may need to start over, here's what I've got so far.

```
--=============================================================================================

SELECT  DB_NAME ()                  PublisherDB
  , sp.name                     AS PublisherName
  , sa.name                     AS TableName
  , UPPER (srv.srvname)         AS SubscriberServerName
  ,*
FROM    dbo.syspublications   sp
JOIN    dbo.sysarticles       sa ON sp.pubid = sa.pubid
JOIN    dbo.syssubscriptions  s ON sa.artid = s.artid
JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers srv ON s.srvid = srv.srvid;


--=============================================================================================
SELECT          DB_NAME ()                    AS db
              , SCHEMA_NAME (o.schema_id)     AS [Schema]
              , so.name                       AS table_name
              , so.type
              , CASE WHEN TABLE_NAME IN (
                              SELECT    TABLE_NAME
                              FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
                              WHERE     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                          ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasPrimaryKey
--INTO            #t2
FROM            sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN      sysobjects                                      so WITH (NOLOCK)
--INNER JOIN #t1 ON t1.
LEFT            OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS t2 ON t2.TABLE_NAME = so.name ON so.id = o.object_id
WHERE           (
        (so.xtype = 'U') -- user table   xtype: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
    OR  (so.xtype = 'V') -- view
    OR  (so.xtype = 'P') -- stored procedure
)
                AND so.category <> 2
                AND so.name IN (
                        SELECT  DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME (objid) FROM  dbo.sysarticles
                    )
ORDER BY        so.name
              , so.type;


--=============================================================================================

DECLARE @jobId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @jobName sysname;

SELECT  @jobId   = jobs.job_id
      , @jobName = jobs.name
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs       jobs (NOLOCK)
JOIN    msdb.dbo.syscategories categories (NOLOCK) ON jobs.category_id = categories.category_id
WHERE   categories.name = 'REPL-Snapshot'
        AND jobs.name LIKE '%db-name%';

SELECT  @jobId
      , @jobName;

EXEC sp_start_job @job_id = @jobId;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up going with.

```
--====================================================================================================================================================
--  Get tables in Snapshot replication for the selected DB.
--====================================================================================================================================================

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t1;

SELECT      pub.name                                                                AS [Publication]
          , CASE WHEN pub.name LIKE '%Snapshot%' THEN 'SnapShot'
                WHEN pub.name LIKE '%Transaction%' THEN 'Transaction' ELSE NULL END AS ReplicationType
          , art.name                                                                AS [Article]
          , serv.name                                                               AS [Subsriber]
          , sub.dest_db                                                             AS [DestinationDB]
          , obj.object_id
          , CASE WHEN obj.type = 'U' THEN 'Table'
                WHEN obj.type = 'V' THEN 'View'
                WHEN obj.type = 'P' THEN 'SP' ELSE NULL END                         AS ObjectType
INTO        #t1
FROM        dbo.syssubscriptions sub
INNER JOIN  sys.servers          serv ON serv.server_id = sub.srvid
INNER JOIN  dbo.sysarticles      art ON art.artid = sub.artid
INNER JOIN  dbo.syspublications  pub ON pub.pubid = art.pubid
INNER JOIN  sys.objects          obj ON obj.object_id = art.objid
WHERE       CASE WHEN pub.name LIKE '%Snapshot%' THEN 'SnapShot'
                WHEN pub.name LIKE '%Transaction%' THEN 'Transaction' ELSE NULL END = 'Snapshot';

--====================================================================================================================================================
--  Check for primary keys on the above tables
--====================================================================================================================================================
SELECT          SCHEMA_NAME (tab.schema_id)                         AS [schema_name]
              , tab.[name]                                          AS table_name
              , pk.[name]                                           AS pk_name
              , SUBSTRING (column_names, 1, LEN (column_names) - 1) AS [columns]
FROM            sys.tables  tab
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes pk ON tab.object_id = pk.object_id
                                  AND   pk.is_primary_key = 1
CROSS APPLY     (
    SELECT      col.[name] + ', '
    FROM        sys.index_columns ic
    INNER JOIN  sys.columns       col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                         AND  ic.column_id = col.column_id
    WHERE       ic.object_id = tab.object_id
                AND ic.index_id = pk.index_id
    ORDER BY    col.column_id
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)                           D(column_names)
WHERE           pk.object_id IN (
                    SELECT  object_id FROM  #t1
                )
ORDER BY        SCHEMA_NAME (tab.schema_id)
              , tab.[name];
```